# Preserve order of classes in a package in testng execution

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, testng, ui-automation

I have a package with 2 classes.

My testng.xml looks like this:

```
<test name="Tests">
 <packages>
   <package name="PackageName"/>
 <packages>
</test>
```

Class2 always runs first followed by Class1.

I want to run Class1 first followed by Class2.
Is this possible from this package level configuration?

Thanks, your answers and pointers are appreciative.

Answer (score 1):

Use `preserve-order="true"` attribute at suite level. Also as specified in the testng's documentation

> By default, TestNG will run your tests in the order they are found in
>   the XML file. If you want the classes and methods listed in this file
>   to be run in an unpredictible order, set the preserve-order attribute
>   to false

So I would suggest you specify your test classes instead of package
EDIT1: In that case run your testng tests programmatically.. Create testng.xml file on the fly by using reflection and adding all the classes to the testng.xml and then run that file 
EDIT2: Java reflections is what you should be looking at..Sharing code may not possible for me now.. but this should get u started: [Get Classes from a package {Java}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection)

Comment: Thanks @Mrunal...The point is there are so many classes in a package, and I would not like to expand my testng.xml file. :(

Comment: In that case run your testng tests programmatically.. Create testng.xml file on the fly by using reflection and adding all the classes to the testng.xml and then run that file

Comment: Sounds promising. Could you share any code snippet kind of?

Comment: check edit2..also you can refer into TestNG's code as well..we do something like that there as well.

Answer (score 0):

By design, TestNG doesn't specify any specific order and it may change between versions.

But it should not be a problem because tests into different classes are supposed to be independant.